# how to check table is using how much space in DB2

Tags: db2

Is there a way in DB2 to identify that a table is consuming how much of the total space allocated to the underlying table space."

Thanks

Comment: What version of DB2?  What platform is it running on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question creates a false dichotomy because a tablespace may be created without allocating a limited amount of space to it. The limitation may rather be the drive or share that the tablespace is on. But if you know the space allocated to a tablespace or only need the percent of a tablespace's current size that a table is using, then yes, there is a way to know.

```
SELECT * FROM SYScat.tables where tabname='mytable';
```

will tell you how many pages a table is using.

Then at the command line: `LiST TABLESPACES SHOW DETAIL` 
will tell you how many total pages are in the tablespace and the size of a page in bytes.

```
Select * from sysibmadm.tbsp_utilization where tbsp_name='MyTblSpace'
```

will give you the maximum size of the tablespace if it has one.

Comment: This answer is only applicable to DB2 running on Linux, UNIX or Windows.  

Furthermore, NPAGES and FPAGES in syscat.tables are only updated when RUNSTATS is executed;  these values may not be accurate.  In addition, they do not include space allocated to indexes, LOBs etc.

Better would be to look at SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO.

Answer (score 10):

### DB2 queries to check the table size

```
select 
   a.CARD*(sum(b.AVGCOLLEN)+10)/1024/1024 as Tablesize_in_MB 
from 
   syscat.tables as a, syscat.columns as b 
where 
   a.TABNAME = b.TABNAME and b.TABNAME = 'TABLE_NAME' group by a.CARD
```

### data size

```
select 
  char(date(t.stats_time))||' '||char(time(t.stats_time)) as statstime 
  ,substr(t.tabschema,1,8)||'.'||substr(t.tabname,1,24) as tabname 
  ,card as rows_per_table 
  ,decimal(float(t.npages)/ ( 1024 / (b.pagesize/1024)),9,2) as used_mb 
  ,decimal(float(t.fpages)/ ( 1024 / (b.pagesize/1024)),9,2) as allocated_mb 
from 
  syscat.tables t , syscat.tablespaces b 
where t.tbspace=b.tbspace 
order by 5 desc with ur
```

### index size

```
select 
  rtrim(substr(i.tabschema,1,8))||'.'||rtrim(substr( i.tabname, 1,24)) as tabname 
 ,decimal(sum(i.nleaf)/( 1024 / (b.pagesize/1024)),12,2) as indx_used_per_table_mb 
from 
   syscat.indexes i, syscat.tables t , syscat.tablespaces b 
where 
   i.tabschema is not null and i.tabname=t.tabname 
   and i.tabschema=t.tabschema and t.tbspace=b.tbspace 
group by 
   i.tabname,i.tabschema, b.pagesize order by 2 desc with ur
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the underlying table **physical size** from the **SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO** table.

The command is given below.

> db2 "SELECT SUBSTR(**TABSCHEMA**,1,15) as SCHEMA, SUBSTR(**TABNAME**,1,20) as
>   TABLENAME, **DATA_OBJECT_P_SIZE** ,**INDEX_OBJECT_P_SIZE** ,
>   **LONG_OBJECT_P_SIZE** , **LOB_OBJECT_P_SIZE** , **XML_OBJECT_P_SIZE**,
>   (DATA_OBJECT_P_SIZE + INDEX_OBJECT_P_SIZE + LONG_OBJECT_P_SIZE +
>   LOB_OBJECT_P_SIZE + XML_OBJECT_P_SIZE ) as **TOTAL_P_SIZE** from
>   SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO where TABNAME=**'table_name'**"

The total physical size is the sum of all the DATA , INDEX, LONG , LOB and XML OBJECT physical sizes (_P_SIZE indicates Physical Size).

You cannot get the tablespace name(even though you could get the tablespace id) from SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO, for that you need to join the above query with **SYSCAT.TABLES**.